# How to print a variable that contains a unicode character?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

```
print u'\u0D05'
a = '\u0D05'
print a
```

`print a` gives `\u0D05` as output but I want to print the unicode character it represents, which is `അ`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\u` escape is not meaningful inside a non-unicode string.  You need to do `a = u'\u0D05'`.

If you're saying you're getting the string from somewhere else and need to interpret unicode escapes in it, then do `print a.decode('unicode-escape')`